# MongoDB query only shows most recent document

Tags: php

i am just starting out with PHP with MongoDB, and what I want to do is to take data from a database, and automatically call it creating individual post divs. But what happens after I implemented the code below is, it just only shows me the most recent one instead of all three documents in a collection that I've actually got...

Here's the code for the function, and i know its a very basic mistake (probably):

```
function get_posts($cursor){
while ($cursor->hasNext()) {
    $entry = $cursor->getNext(); 
    $blog_body = "";
    $blog_body = $blog_body . '<div class="wrap-it">';
    $blog_body = $blog_body . '<div class="jumbotron">';
    $blog_body = $blog_body . '<div class="container">';
    $blog_body = $blog_body . "<h2>" . $entry['title'] ."</h2>";
    $blog_body = $blog_body . "<p>". $entry['description'] ."</p>";
    $blog_body = $blog_body . '<p><a class="rec-btn">Read more &raquo;</a></p>';
    $blog_body = $blog_body . '</div></div></div>';
  }
  return $blog_body;
 }
```

And is called like this:

```
<?php $posts = get_posts($cursor);
  echo $posts; ?>
```

Comment: $cursor is created how?

Comment: try {
    $mongo = new Mongo();
    $database   = $mongo->selectDB('choqlet');
    $collection = $database->selectCollection('entries');
}
catch(MongoConnectionException $e)
{
    die("Failed to connect to database ".$e->getMessage());
}
 
$cursor = $collection->find();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fault is with ***$blog_body = ""*** (move it prior to the while loop):

```
function get_posts($cursor){
  $blog_body = "";
  while ($cursor->hasNext()) {
    $entry = $cursor->getNext(); 
    $blog_body = $blog_body . '<div class="wrap-it">';
    $blog_body = $blog_body . '<div class="jumbotron">';
    $blog_body = $blog_body . '<div class="container">';
    $blog_body = $blog_body . "<h2>" . $entry['title'] ."</h2>";
    $blog_body = $blog_body . "<p>". $entry['description'] ."</p>";
    $blog_body = $blog_body . '<p><a class="rec-btn">Read more &raquo;</a></p>';
    $blog_body = $blog_body . '</div></div></div>';
  }
  return $blog_body;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

On this line you are resetting the $blog_body content for each new iteration.

```
$blog_body = "";
```

Call it this way

```
function get_posts($cursor) {
    $blog_body = "";

    while ($cursor->hasNext()) {
        $entry = $cursor->getNext(); 

        $blog_body .= '<div class="wrap-it">';
        $blog_body .= '<div class="jumbotron">';
        $blog_body .= '<div class="container">';
        $blog_body .= "<h2>" . $entry['title'] ."</h2>";
        $blog_body .= "<p>". $entry['description'] ."</p>";
        $blog_body .= '<p><a class="rec-btn">Read more &raquo;</a></p>';
        $blog_body .= '</div></div></div>';
    }

    return $blog_body;
}
```